# Java Changing variable from another class and the depending values

Tags: java

I have a problem with my class variables, as always ^^
So I'm constructing a class named Prng, with variables

```
private int randListSize = 10; 
private byte randList[] = new byte[randListSize]; 
private byte[] seed = new byte[]{ 34, -70, -4, 117, 98 };
```

the getters/setters associated
and the method

```
public void prng() {
        SecureRandom random;
        try {
            random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"); 
            random.setSeed(seed);
            random.nextBytes(randList); 
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in another class named Test.java, I want to :
1) set randListSize to /number of random bytes I want
2) have the randList of this size, and not from original 10 size

whenever I try, my randList is always of size 10. Can you help me please ?
in my class Test I've written :

```
Prng prng = new Prng();
System.out.println(prng.getRandListSize() + " " + prng.getRandList().length);
prng.setRandListSize(11);
System.out.println(prng.getRandListSize()+ " " + prng.getRandList().length);
```

which returns me "10 10 ; 11 10" and I want "11 11" at the end.

EDIT : here's my getters/setters :

```
public int getRandListSize() {
    return randListSize;
}

public void setRandListSize(int randListSize) {
    this.randListSize = randListSize;
}

public byte[] getSeed() {
    return seed;
}

public void setSeed(byte[] seed) {
    this.seed = seed;
}

public byte[] getRandList() {
    return randList;
}

public void setRandList(byte[] randList) {
    this.randList = randList;
}
```

Comment: Can you show `setRandListSize()` and `getRandList()`?

Comment: `public int getRandListSize() {
  return randListSize;
 }

public void setRandListSize(int randListSize) {
  this.randListSize = randListSize;
 }
`
I used the automatic way of eclipse to do it ^^
I think I'll have the same problem with my seed, because it will be loaded from a "password.txt" file (turned into bytes)

Comment: Could you update your question with that info? Properly formatted code goes a long way towards getting a good response.

Comment: Edit the question, don't wedge code into illegible comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `randListSize`, in my opinion, is a useless field, as that property can be retrieved directly from the array, and as the operation isn't expensive the value doesn't need to be cached. Thus, you really don't need getters/setters for that field either. I see you're using it as an initial size variable, but in that case I think it'd be better for it to be a parameter for a constructor/factory method instead, as it really doesn't need to be used anywhere else.

Second, `setRandListSize()` doesn't actually change `randList`'s size, as arrays, once created, cannot be structurally modified (i.e. you can't make arrays longer/shorter after creating them). You're just changing an unrelated variable, which leads to some confusion once `randListSize` stops matching `randList.length`. This is the reason you're seeing `11 10` instead of `11 11` -- `randListSize` is only used at the moment of array creation, and later changes to `randListSize` don't affect the array.

In order to get the result you want, you're going to have to allocate an entirely new array and set `randList` to point to it instead of your old one, which you can do using your `setRandList()` method. Alternatively, you can write a method, perhaps called `createNewRandList(int newLength)`, to do all the work at once.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setRandListSize` method will need to recreate the `randList` array. If you need to keep the data in it, your method should copy whatever data can fit into the new array.

```
public void setRandListSize(int randListSize) {
    this.randListSize = randListSize;
    this.randList = new byte[randListSize];
}
```

Comment: ah ok, thank you for your response ! what is the difference between `private byte randList[]` and `private byte[] randList` ? I had to change the first one to the second (else it didn't work with your function). I'll edit the seed to ^^

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. See new version.

Comment: @user3719373 There's no difference between `private byte randList[]` and `private byte[] randList`, except that the first one is considered somewhat obsolete, and I think it was put in the language just because C programmers were used to it.  The second form makes it clear that you're defining a variable whose type is `byte[]`, i.e. an array of bytes.  I recommend using that syntax.